# Titanium - Make annotation at the user's location

Tags: iphone, annotations, geolocation, titanium, appcelerator

I am an iPhone developer and a beginner in using Titanium studio. I started to learn Titanium few days back and worked on some samples which uses view, navgroup, images, etc. I'd like to step advance. Now I need to open a mapView in a window and annotate a pin on the user's current location. I have opened a mapView now. I have no idea in getting the user's latitude & longitude and to make annotation at that point. Help me to proceed further with any code or samples. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may get the geoposition by [Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Geolocation-module). And for annotation try [this example](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Map-module):

```
var mountainView = Titanium.Map.createAnnotation({
    latitude:37.390749,
    longitude:-122.081651,
    title:"Appcelerator Headquarters",
    subtitle:'Mountain View, CA',
    pincolor:Titanium.Map.ANNOTATION_RED,
    animate:true,
    leftButton: '../images/appcelerator_small.png',
    myid:1 // CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE THAT IS PASSED INTO EVENT OBJECTS
});

var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
    mapType: Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
    region: {latitude:33.74511, longitude:-84.38993, 
            latitudeDelta:0.01, longitudeDelta:0.01},
    animate:true,
    regionFit:true,
    userLocation:true,
    annotations:[mountainView]
});

win.add(mapview);
```

hope it helps :)